# Have plugin write to media folder

Tags: wordpress, fwrite, multisite

I'm working with WordPress multi site and have a plugin that zips up all files of type x and stores them in a root directory of the master site. When I change the directory to be part of the sub-site I get write errors (I'm using the uploads directory as the location to be stored in). What is the correct way on multi-site to write a file to the sub-site. I'll be doing it quite a bit so would rather get it right now (and I don't want to change the file permissions to 777 for security).

Currently I define the path here:

define( 'DOCPATH', get_site_url().'/wp-content/uploads/');

Which leads to an error when fwrite is called:
Error: Can't write to log folder http://example.com/site01/wp-content/uploads/ Permissions 777 needed.

I'd write to the root and be ok with that (well I wouldn't be but it'd get it done) except the sites are set to auto-delete after 30 days so I need to ensure that the generated file is deleted too.

Comment: Normally you would use [the wp_upload_dir function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_dir/) to get the right directory. Everythign else should be handeled by Wordpress and/or the Multisite Plugin.

Comment: Thanks D B you got me on the right track ended up using: $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
$upload_path = $uploads['path'].'/test/'; define( 'DOCPATH', get_site_url().'/wp-content/uploads/');

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it clearer working off D B's guidance this is how the finished solution looked:

```
$uploads = wp_upload_dir();
$upload_path = $uploads['path'];
define( 'DOCPATH',$upload_path);
```

Files happily reside in the uploads directory now of each multi-site.